# How to track google maps interactions with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get users interactions in google map (zoom in/out, map changed) that is embedded with iframe in my website. I read lots of articles for submiting Forms, but with iframe maps, could not find a way. **Which is the right trigger**, in order to accoplish that?

For now, I have created a custom HTML tag that has this kind of code:

```
<script>
  try {
    var postObject = JSON.stringify({
      event: 'mapChanged',
    });
    parent.postMessage(postObject, 'https://www.example.com/contact/');
  } catch(e) {
    window.console && window.console.log(e);
  }
</script>
```

and a trigger that has this options:

- **Page View** and **Page URL equals** to: https://www.example.com/contact/

Because of the trigger I could see the tag in GTM, but of course this is not correct.. I do not want to trigger every time a user visit the contact page, but when clicks on the map or zoom in/out